# Getting nullpointerExep while creating swing panel and frame in two different classes in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have created two classes named **Graphic** and **Objects**. In my graphics class, i have created a method which creates the frame. In the objects class, i want to create the components, all the JLabels, JPanels and so on, so one class don't gets to big. Right now i have 300+ lines of code in 1 class.

**Graphic class:**

```
public class Graphic extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Runnable, InterfaceI {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;

private static double kWh;
private static double liter;
private static double temp;

private static String message = "Message";
private static String message2 = "Message";
private static String message3 = "Message";

private static boolean connection = true;

private Objects obj = new Objects();

protected Graphic() throws RemoteException {
    super();

    // Create objects
    obj.createGuiObjects(frame, panel, kWh, liter, temp, message, message2, message3, connection);
}

public void createFrame() {

    // Create window
    frame = new JFrame(); // Create a new frame
    frame.setSize(900, 400); // Sets size         
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Monitor Service"); // Sets title
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Sets the window on the center of the screen
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Objects class:**

```
public void createGuiObjects(JFrame frame, JPanel panel, double kWh, double liter, double temp, String message, String message2, String message3, boolean connection) {

"All my labels and so on.

panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4, 10, 5));
panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
panel.setBackground(Color.decode("#34495e"));
panel.add(radiatorpanel);
panel.add(temppanel);
panel.add(waterpanel);
panel.add(powerpanel);
```

Don't know if its possible to send panels as parameters, because i'm still getting an nullpointer exception in my graphics class where i'm running the line **frame.add(panel);**

Is this a bad way to split it, or should i just hold all GUI elemets in one class?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  An MCVE can contain more than one class, but only one public class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you never intialize `private JPanel panel` in `Graphics`.

```
obj.createGuiObjects(frame, panel, kWh, liter, temp, message, message2, message3, connection);
```

creates your `Objects` but aslong you leave

```
private JPanel panel;
```

as it is, which results in

```
frame.add(panel);
```

always will thrown an exception because panel will always stay default => `null`.

So you need some kind of getter to get access to the JPanel you created in `Objects`

```
public JPanel getInstance() { return this.panel; }
```

and in `Graphics`

```
panel = ob.getInstance();
```